# Git diff with textutil

Tags: macos, git, git-diff, git-difftool

I want to compare .doc or .docx files with `git diff` using `textutil`.  For example: `textutil 'Hello.doc' -convert txt -stdout`.  But I cannot figure out how to put that in my configuration file with arguments without writing a new git difftool.  I also tried [using catdoc](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes), but realized that it doesn't work with .docx.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out the instructions in "Defining an External Diff Driver" in Git Help pages?

In git attributes you would specify types for doc and docx and in git config you would specify your conversion proces.  Something like ( I have no way of testing this unfortunately)

Attributes

```
*.docx diff=docxdiff
```

Config

```
[diff "docxdiff"]
    command = textutil -convert txt -stdout
```

[Git attributes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html)